# Eliminar número en posición fija en una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo la siguiente lista.

```
mylist = [(-65.35170344799997, -22.979064216999973, 0.0), (-65.35155106799994, -22.979434281999943, 0.0), (-65.35173972899997, -22.97957940699996, 0.0), (-65.35244357999994, -22.980711373999952, 0.0)]
```

Donde los primeros números corresponden a la latitud y longitud y el tercero (0.0) corresponde al nivel sobre el mar.
¿Cómo puedo eliminar la tercera posición de la lista?, ya que, no siempre puede contener la lista el valor 0.0 y puede variar.

```
 mylist = [(-65.35170344799997, -22.979064216999973), (-65.35155106799994, -22.979434281999943), (-65.35173972899997, -22.97957940699996), (-65.35244357999994, -22.980711373999952)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres eliminar el tercer valor de todas las tuplas puedes usar slicing junto a una lista por compresión:

```
>>> mylist = [(-65.35170344799997, -22.979064216999973, 0.0),
              (-65.35155106799994, -22.979434281999943, 0.0), 
              (-65.35173972899997, -22.97957940699996, 0.0), 
              (-65.35244357999994, -22.980711373999952, 0.0)]


>>> mylist = [sublist[:2] for sublist in mylist]
>>> mylist
[(-65.35170344799997, -22.979064216999973),
 (-65.35155106799994, -22.979434281999943),
 (-65.35173972899997, -22.97957940699996),
 (-65.35244357999994, -22.980711373999952)]
```

Simplemente se itera con un `for` sobre `mylist` para ir obteniendo las tuplas. Por cada tupla se hace un rebanado (*slicing*) de la misma (`sublist[:2]`), que obtiene los elementos desde el inicio hasta el indice 1 (los dos primeros elementos) si es que existen.